# Dictionary App constantly downloading dictionaries

Tags: macos, mac, dictionary

I've been unable to use my Dictionary App for a few days, as it consistently says that it is downloading the dictionaries. I can't find out why it started downloading them again (it already had them), or how to check on the state of a download, or where it is downloading from. I am at a loss as to how to diagnose this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this problem once in a while, and find that it's due to the *DictionaryServiceHelper* process freezing. To fix it, first I quit *Dictionary*, and then I open a terminal and type:

```
pkill -9 DictionaryServiceHelper
```

Yes, you really do need to send the dangerous SIGKILL (signal 9) in this case.

If you're not a command line person, you can alternatively open *Activity Monitor*, search for *DictionaryServiceHelper*, and force quit it.

Answer (score 2):

This kept happening to me too, again with the recent update to 10.13.4. In dictionary preferences, I had selected multiple dictionaries. Turning them off, restarting the app, and turning them back on resolved the issue.