# Dictionary app stuck on 'Downloading Dictionaries' & lookup not working

Tags: dictionary

For several days now, the Dictionary app is stuck on Downloading Dictionaries. I am connected to high-speed Internet and restarted the machine several times.

Even tried the suggestions here (related issue): [Dictionary App constantly downloading dictionaries](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306195/dictionary-app-constantly-downloading-dictionaries)

Even the built-in lookup feature (Select a word, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+Click -> LookUp selected word meaning) is not working since this issue came up.

macOS Version: Ventura 13.4

[image: Screenshot of the Dictionary app 'Downloading Dictionaries' dialog box]